# Unable to stub helper method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am trying to stub a method on a helper that is defined in my controller. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= authenticated_user_method
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end

module SomeHelper
  def do_something
    current_user.call_a_method
  end
end
```

In my Rspec:

```
describe SomeHelper
  it "why cant i stub a helper method?!" do
    helper.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    helper.respond_to?(:current_user).should be_true # Fails
    helper.do_something # Fails 'no method current_user'
  end
end
```

In `spec/support/authentication.rb`

```
module RspecAuthentication
  def sign_in(user)
    controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(user)
    controller.stub!(:authenticate!).and_return(true)

    helper.stub(:current_user).and_return(user) if respond_to?(:helper)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RspecAuthentication, :type => :controller
  config.include RspecAuthentication, :type => :view
  config.include RspecAuthentication, :type => :helper
end
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998491/stub-a-controller-helper-method-in-a-helper-spec), but settled on a work around. This strange behavior has creeped up again and I would like to understand *why* this doesnt work.

*UPDATE*: I have found that calling `controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)` before `helper.stub!(...)` is what is causing this behavior. This is easy enough to fix in `spec/support/authentication.rb`, but is this a bug in Rspec? I dont see why it would be expected to not be able to stub a method on a helper if it was already stubbed on a controller.

Comment: Try stubbing the method through ApplicationController, since that is where it is defined. `ApplicationController.stub(:current_user => @user)` EDIT: Now I'm thinking that might not work.

Comment: No, it didnt work. I tried `any_instance` too with no luck. I have actually got it working, but I am a bit confused (may have found a bug with rspec). I will update the question shortly.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It's definitely worth filing an issue at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues (and trying with the latest version).

Comment: Created ticket: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/135

Comment: i have same issue, does have any solutions yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
describe SomeHelper
  before :each do
    @helper = Object.new.extend SomeHelper
  end

  it "why cant i stub a helper method?!" do
    @helper.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    # ...
  end
end
```

The first part is based on [this reply](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/340#issuecomment-909063) by the author of RSpec, and the second part is based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509689/500776).

Comment: ... and then the tests actually need to test @helper, not SomeHelper.

Answer (score 22):

Update to Matthew Ratzloff's answer: You don't need the instance object and stub! has been deprecated

```
it "why can't I stub a helper method?!" do
  helper.stub(:current_user) { user }
  expect(helper.do_something).to eq 'something'
end
```

Edit. The RSpec 3 way to `stub!` would be:

`allow(helper).to receive(:current_user) { user }`

See: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/

Comment: I fixed my answer for RSpec 3.

Answer (score 18):

In RSpec 3.5 RSpec, it seems like `helper` is no longer accessible from an `it` block. (It will give you the following message:

> `helper` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

(I can't seem to find any documentation on this change, this is all knowledge gained experimentally).

The key to solving this is knowing that helper methods are instance methods, and that for your own helper methods it's easy to do this:

```
allow_any_instance_of( SomeHelper ).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

This is what finally worked for me

Footnotes/Credit Where Credit Due:

- [Super Props to a blog entry by Johnny Ji about their struggles stubbing helper/instance methods](http://johnnyji.me/rspec/2015/06/18/stubbing-controller-instance-methods-in-rspec.html)

Answer (score 5):

Rspec 3

```
  user = double(image: urlurl)
  allow(helper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  expect(helper.get_user_header).to eq("/uploads/user/1/logo.png")
```

Answer (score 5):

As of RSpec 3.10, this technique will work:

```
  before do
    without_partial_double_verification { 
      allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    }
  end
```

The `without_partial_double_verification` wrapper is needed to avoid a `MockExpectationError` unless you have that turned off globally.

Comment: I was in a controller spec so I used `allow(controller).to receive`. 

The `without_partial_double_verification` was not needed in my case.

Worked  like a charm

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in the case of RSpec 3:

```
let(:user) { create :user }
helper do
  def current_user; end
end
before do
  allow(helper).to receive(:current_user).and_return user
end
```

Comment: Very clever. First you define missing method (from another helper, controller) in your helper and then stub it. Can the `def ...` block use directly `user`, so no stub is needed?